# Unable to connect to MySQL from Android using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL from an android device by following this tutorial: http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/connecting-to-mysql-database-t50063.html.

All thats happening is that it is printing the ip address of the server I wish to connect to on the emulator. It shows the following errors in the logcat:

```
    12-08 11:42:01.993: I/dalvikvm(274): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 12-08 11:42:02.113: I/dalvikvm(274): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 12-08 11:42:03.273: E/log_tag(274): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value
 <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
 12-08 11:45:58.283: E/log_tag(351): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  
 <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
  12-08 11:53:11.302: E/log_tag(378): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 
  <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 12-08 12:03:31.643: E/log_tag(405): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  
 <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
 12-08 12:20:57.052: E/log_tag(432): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 
 <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Below is a copy of my java file:

```
package com.david.Connect;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class ConnectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

       TextView txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 
        // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML. 
        LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
        txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
        rootLayout.addView(txt); 
        setContentView(rootLayout); 

        // Set the text and call the connect function. 
        txt.setText("Connecting...");
      //call the method to run the data retreival
        txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));



    }
    public static final String KEY_121 = "http://86.47.59.249/employee.php";



    private String getServerData(String returnString) {

       InputStream is = null;

       String result = "";
        //the year data to send
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code","1"));

//http post
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}

//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
//parse json data
try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("EmployeeId")+
                        ", name: "+json_data.getString("First_Name")+
                        ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("Last_Name")+
                        ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("Birth_Date")
                );
                //Get an output to the screen
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }
}catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
return returnString;
    }   

    }
```

and here is my php file which I have on the server 86.47.59.29 where the MySQL Database is:

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("86.47.59.249","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("Test");

    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Employee WHERE     
    EmployeeId>'".mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST['code'])."'");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

And below is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.david.Connect"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ConnectActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        </manifest>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Its driving me nuts!

Thanks

Comment: You should urgently change your php script - change `$_REQUEST['code']` to `mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST['code'])`.  Without this change, anyone reading this post has enough information to easily compromise your database and potentially your server using SQL injection.  See this page for background reading: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thanks just changed that there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I visit http://86.47.59.249/employee.php in a browser, I get a 404 error. This is because your PHP script is either not set up correctly, or not where you think it is.

You need to do two things:

In you Java, check the response code of the request. You can do this like so:

```
// ...
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
StatusLine responseStatus = response.getStatusLine();
if (responseStatus.getStatusCode() != 200) {
  // Handle error here
} else {
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  // ...
```

In your PHP, you need to handle potential errors:

```
<?php

  // Database connection settings
  $dbHost = '86.47.59.249';
  $dbUser = 'username';
  $dbPass = 'password';
  $dbName = 'Test';

  // Try and connect to the database
  if (!mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Oh No! Something went wrong connecting to the database: '.mysql_error());
  } else if (!mysql_select_db($dbName)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Oh No! Something went wrong selecting the database: '.mysql_error());
  }

  // Define SQL query
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM Tbl_Employee
            WHERE EmployeeId > '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['code'])."'";

  // Try and execute the query
  if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Oh No! Something went wrong with the query: '.mysql_error());
  }

  // Fetch all results into an array
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[] = $e;
  }

  // Close database link
  // You can safely leave this line out, PHP implicitly does this when
  // it terminates
  mysql_close();

  // Exit with a JSON encoded string of the results
  exit(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: When you enter http://86.47.59.249/employee.php the reason you cant access it is because that isnt the actual address Im using. However when I enter the real address I get a 404 error but if I enter the address using ftp:// intead of http:// I can connect. Is there any way of incorporating ftp into my php file?

Comment: @davemc An FTP server will not invoke (run) the PHP script and give you the output, it will merely give you the PHP source code. You need to get the PHP script working on your web server. If it is a valid web server, I guess it's probably just a matter of moving the script to the correct directory to allow it to be served as a web page.

Comment: OK I have just found out I was connecting to the wrong server. It turns out that my PC is the one hosting the MySQLServer. Im kind of confused now cos I dont think this is a webserver. When i run localhost\employee.php it just gives me the option to open or save the file. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have PHP installed on your machine, or the web server is not correctly set up to handle .php files with PHP. Do you have a proper PHP enabled web server that you can use?

Comment: No the only webserver I have on this machine is Internet Information Services. What would you recommend I use? Sorry for wrecking your head about this!

Comment: @davemc I tend to use Apache for PHP, I hate IIS. You should install the latest Apache 2.2.x Windows installer package first, then PHP 5.2.17, and select it to set up Apache 2.2 in the installation process. You will need to point the PHP installer to the Apache configuration directory during the install, which if you leave all the paths as default during Apache installation will be `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf`. You then place your PHP script in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs`.

Comment: [Apache download link](http://mirrors.enquira.co.uk/apache/httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.21-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi) - [PHP download link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.2.17-Win32-VC6-x86.msi)

Comment: While installing PHP, make sure that you choose to install the `mysqli` extension and (at least) the MySQL driver for `PDO` in the extensions screen. It is also worth installing: `mysql`, `zip`, `sockets`, `mbstring`, `mcrypt`, `gd2`, `ldap`. If you are installing MySQL on your local machine, I tend to do it last, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Nice one I'll give that a go now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open up that page (employee.php) on the browser, do View Source (CTRL+U on most browsers) and make sure that only a JSON string is being returned, as it clearly fails on trying to parse the result into a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox with the firebug extension to see what data your php script is returning. You most likely are not using the correct JSON.get* function.